# How can we find smallest singular value of Jacobian matrix of a system of nonlinear equations without finding the solution?

Tags: jacobian

To solve a system of nonlinear equations which are equal to zero, ${f_i}(X) = 0\forall i \in 1:n,X = \left[ {{x_1},{x_2}, \cdots ,{x_n}} \right]$, we use Jacobian matrix and Newton algorithm. Hence, at each iteration, updated $X$ can be find by the following equation

${X^{(k + 1)}} = {X^{(k)}} + {J^{ - 1}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{f_i}({X^{(k)}})} \\ 
  {{f_2}({X^{(k)}})} \\ 
   \vdots  \\ 
  {{f_m}({X^{(k)}})} 
\end{array}} \right]k = 0:j$

Where $J = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}\\
{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}
\end{array}} \right]$

After finding the solution ${X^j}$ Jacobian is a known and constant matrix. I am wondering if there is a way to find minimum singular value of $J(X^j)$ before running the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python / scipy, see
[svds](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html):

```
# k smallest singular values --
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
k = 1
sing = svds( AA, which="SM", k=k, tol=1e-4, return_singular_vectors=False )
```

This uses the Arpack software package, fast and solid.  (`sparse.linalg` is a red herring:
`svds` does dense, sparse, and LinOps too.)